# Is there a way to exclude html lines from being formatted in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

is there a way to exclude html lines from being formatted in vscode? (I use prettier)e.g.: I manually format  like so:

```
<input 
            (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" 
            #title type="text" 
            class="form-control" />
```

and it will be reformatted automatically to:

```
<input (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" #title type="text" class="form-control" />
```

I tried with `pre` which is working but this is not very handy.

Here is my recent (uncomfortable) solution as example;

```
 <style>
    pre {
      white-space: normal;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0 0;
      border: 0px;
    }
</style>
<div>
    **<pre>**   
    <input 
        (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" 
        #title type="text" 
        class="form-control" />
    **</pre>**

    <!-- other HTML to be formatted -->

    <ul class="list-group">
        **<pre>**
            <li  
                class="list-group-item" 
                *ngFor="let item of items">
                <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
            </li>
        **</pre>**
    </ul>
</div>
```

thanx, dukehh

Comment: What is version of your VS?

Comment: Version 1.19.2 (1.19.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code itself does not perform auto-formatting of any language. You would need to look at the extension you are using and if it offers the ability to disable auto-format on save and such.